# Rails 3: Measure database performance (MongoDB and MySQL)

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

I set up my Rails application twice. One is working with MongoDB (Mongoid as mapper) and the other with MySQL and ActiveRecord. Then I wrote a rake task which inserts some test-data to both databases (100.000 entries). 
I measured how long it takes for each database with the ruby Benchmark module. I did some testing with 100 and 10.000 entries where mongodb was always faster than mysql (about 1/3). The weird thing is that it takes about 3 times longer in mongodb to insert the 100.000 entries than with mysql. I have no idea why mongodb has this behaviour?! The only thing that I know is that the cpu time is much lower than the total time. Is it possible that mongodb starts some sort of garbage collection while it's inserting the data? At the beginning it's fast, but as more data mongodb is inserting, it gets slower and slower...any idea on this?

To get somehow a read performance of the two databases, I thought about measuring the time when the database gets an search query and respond the result. As I need some precise measurements, I don't want to include the time where Rails is processing my query from the controller to the database.

How do I do the measurement directly at the database and not in the Rails controller? Is there any gem / tool which would help me?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Updated my question according to my current situation

Comment: As a general thought: which is the application you are planning your database for? By your descibed approach, you will be able to measure response time of the databases, not their speed and neither their scalability in terms of multiple connections and so on.

Comment: The application will run on MongoDB at the end. However, I need a comparison which one would be handle the main query (it's a search algorithm) faster. So I would need to measure the speed of the database and maybe the capacity. I need to clear what would happen if many users are making this search request at the same time.

Comment: Generally for large sets of data MongoDB should always win. Besides the performance the true question is whether you need a fast database or data integrity.

Comment: @luacassus: do you have some hard data to support your claim? :)

Comment: I solved the first question by myself, as I implemented a rake task which make the inserts to the db. Also I found that ruby comes with a benchmark module, which I use to measure the time (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html#method-c-benchmark). However, the measurement is not as close at the database as I wanted, but I leave it now as it is.
The question is what is the best possibility to measure the search query?? Please help...

Comment: Sergio is right, it could be possible that mysql is faster. Later I want to try some tweaks on mysql to get a better performance as with the standard configuration. But first I have to make a precise measurement of my search algorithm...

Comment: I would extract the "kernel" of the algorithm (the minimal functionality, that is crucial for your scenario) and test it against different databases with preloaded data, that are most similar to the data in production. Actually I do that to compare ActiveRecord with my Ruby Object Database in Rod Benchmark Project -  https://github.com/apohllo/rod-benchmark/wiki

Answer (score 1):

If your base goal is to measure database performance time at the DB level, I would recommend you get familiar with the [benchRun](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/JS+Benchmarking+Harness) method in MongoDB.

To do the type of thing you want to do, you can get started with the example on the linked page, here is a variant with explanations:

```
// skipped dropping the table and reinitializing as I'm assuming you have your test dataset
// your database is called test and collection is foo in this code
ops = [
// this sets up an array of operations benchRun will run
   { 
      // possible operations include find (added in 2.1), findOne, update, insert, delete, etc.
      op : "find" ,   
      // your db.collection
      ns : "test.foo" ,  
      // different operations have different query options - this matches based on _id
      // using a random value between 0 and 100 each time
      query : { _id : { "#RAND_INT" : [ 0 , 100 ] } }
   }
]

for ( x = 1; x<=128; x*=2){
    // actual call to benchRun, each time using different number of threads
    res = benchRun( { parallel : x ,   // number of threads to run in parallel
                      seconds : 5 ,    // duration of run; can be fractional seconds
                      ops : ops        // array of operations to run (see above)
                    } )
    // res is a json object returned, easiest way to see everything in it:
    printjson( res )
    print( "threads: " + x + "\t queries/sec: " + res.query )
}
```

If you put this in a file called testing.js you can run it from mongo shell like this:

```
> load("testing.js")
{
    "note" : "values per second",
    "errCount" : NumberLong(0),
    "trapped" : "error: not implemented",
    "queryLatencyAverageMs" : 69.3567923734754,
    "insert" : 0,
    "query" : 12839.4,
    "update" : 0,
    "delete" : 0,
    "getmore" : 0,
    "command" : 128.4
}
threads: 1   queries/sec: 12839.4
```

and so on.

Comment: It works only with "findOne" for me. With "find" I got "don't understand op: find" from the mongo shell. Does it depend on the version, as I use 1.8.2 which is not the newest one.
Is there also such a measurement for mysql where I can compare the results?

Comment: my bad - I'm using 2.1.1 which is not a production release - in fact find does not work in your version, nor 2.0.3 which I just tried it in.  I think findOne would give you metrics to start with - obviously it's not completely comparable to doing a find, but it's better than nothing :) till you upgrade to 2.2 when it's out (or you can try 2.1.1 if this is just for testing).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I could try to update mongodb, but if there is no similar test with mysql, it doesn't make sense. I have to compare the results of the two databases. It is probably the best solution to create the tests in Rails as I can run the same tests on mongodb and mysql. I found ActiveSupport::Notification, maybe this one works for me. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Notifications.html

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why MongoDB is getting slower while inserting many documents.

> Many to many relations are not recommended for over 10,000 documents when using MRI due to the garbage collector taking over 90% of the run time when calling #build or #create. This is due to the large array appending occuring in these operations.
>   http://mongoid.org/performance.html

Now I would like to know how to measure the query performance of each database. My main concerns are the the measurement of the query time and the flow capacity / throughput. This measurement should be made directly at the database, so that nothing can adulterate the result.

Comment: it would be easier to give a specific answer if you can describe what type of query you will be running.

Comment: Just write the code with ActiveRecord activated and configured. This is really easy. You need only the connection details and schema of the DB. If you need inspiration look at the benchmark I wrot: https://github.com/apohllo/rod-benchmark/tree/master/lib/rod/benchmark/active_record